# Attask - Create a new user via API

Tags: c#, attask

I am integrating a .Net application with Work-front, I am supposed to create a new user in work-front from API. I have tried the steps mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440970/attask-user-creation) and my code `https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/user?updates={emailAddr:testuserAPI@domain.com,firstName:testuser,lastName:API}&username=myname@domain.com&password=password&method=post`

*From my console application I get internal server error 500. From fiddler I get parse error*.

`https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/5.0/user?updates={"emailAddr":"testuserAPI@domain.com","firstName":"testuser","lastName":"sample","roleID":"testrole","password":"pwd123res"}&method=post&sessionID=sdfdsdf1`

Above code gives *unrecognized URI format: too many parts - exception*

Though my requirement is to authorise using API key, I was trying possible ways of achieving it.But I am not able to create in any of the ways.However, I am able to create from UI, which confirms my ID has rights to create user. I did look into API explorer and could see named functions,but whats the approach?Is there any documentation for these complete steps? My search was in-vain. Please suggest as I am new bee to workfront. Thanks in advance!

Update 1:

I was able to create a user via the API authorising by both API key and sessionID. The parameter I missed to pass is username (not necessarily an existing username).  My code is -

`https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/user?updates={"firstName":"Test","lastName":"API","username":"TestAPI@domain.com","emailAddr":"test2@test.com"}&method=post&apiKey=t---------------------u`

My first step is resolved. There are 2 more steps which I need to perform. Calling named action - assignUserToken. I tried the code as below and it didn't work
`https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/5.0/user/ID=4556ffs3324?action=assignUserToken&apiKey=t---------------u&method=put`

ID is value returned while creating a user. Error returned is -
 *{"error":{"class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"null objCode"}}*

Can you share the syntax of calling this named action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Your call has a few things wrong with It
1st you are calling

```
api/5.0
```

this needs to be

```
api/v5.0
```

2nd you are calling

```
api/v5.0/user/ID=4556ffs3324
```

it should be

```
api/v5.0/user/4556ffs3324
```

Other then that I dont see anything else wrong with the call.

Comment: Thanks @michael. It worked! The complete URL would be `https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v5.0/user/5--4425f?action=completeUserRegistration&updates={"firstName":"Test","lastName":"UserAPI","token":"0---6","title":"testUser","newPassword":"Password01"}&method=put&apiKey=fdgfdg0l`

Comment: where did you get the token from?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user via API is a 3 step process as mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440970/attask-user-creation) but it doesn't have syntax. The syntax and steps are as below.

1. Create user -
   `https://{yourcompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/user?updates={"firstName":"Test","lastName":"API","username":"TestAPI@domain.com","emailAddr":"test@domain.com"}&method=post&apiKey=-----0l`

This would return a uniqe ID on response. Use this ID value for next step.

2. Assign userToken - 
   `https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v5.0/user/12345?action=assignUserToken&apiKey=d---l&method=put`

ID value is 12345. This would further return a token. Use this token value for next step.

3. Complete userRegistration- `https://{mycompany}.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v5.0/user/12345?action=completeUserRegistration&updates={"firstName":"Test","lastName":"API","token":"0--ab","title":"testUser","newPassword":"Password01"}&method=put&apiKey=dqy---3`

That completes all the process. Now check in workfront UI.